# How to send data to local callable function? (Firebase CLI Shell)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I recently found Firebase CLI Shell, which allows me to run functions locally before using them in my app.

The problem is, I can't find the way to send the required data to the function.

One example is this one:

```
exports.followUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
//...all the code here
});
```

This function uses data.otherID to know which user it has to follow. It's already working inside my app, as I call it this way:

```
followUser = (itemid) => {
    var followUserFunction = 
    firebase.functions().httpsCallable('followUser');
    followUserFunction({
        thisID: this.state.currentUser.uid,
        otherID: itemid
    }).then(function (result) {
       //some other code here
    }).then(() => {
        this.loadUsers();
    });
}
```

I send both thisID and otherID strings and then use it inside the function.

But how can I send the same data through the console? I'm testing new functions and I can't find a way to test them locally without having to add them to my front-end app, which takes a lot of time as I'm not experienced in React Native nor I'm the one in charge of front-end in my project.

I run

> firebase experimental:functions:shell

in my console, it shows me a list with all my functions, but then I get lost when it comes to sending data.

Many thanks!

Comment: Callables are not very well supported for local testing in the shell.  The best you can do today is stated in the duplicate.

Comment: @DougStevenson I asked this question again because the duplicate wasn't useful to me. You say we can test them just like any other function, but I can't find the way to send the same data I send from my front-end, that's where I get stuck. The documentation isn't being really useful as it uses other functions like onCreate or onUpdate.
I need to send two or more parameters in an object to the function, isn't that possible? Thanks

Comment: I said in the dup that callables can be tested like any other **HTTPS** type function.  Not **any** other function.  Callables are essentially HTTPS functions with some extra features, so you should test them like HTTPS functions for now, using knowledge of how callables work.  Callables testing will improve in the future, but this is the best you have for now.